# IllegalStateException at start up Spring JUnit test

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea, junit, mockmvc

I've made a simple Maven Spring REST project. (this one: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Afterwards I made a simple JUnit test using MockMVC to test the REST functionality. In this case: does my code respond to /greeting?

When I run my test (using IntelliJ) I get this IllegalStateException.

How can I resolve this?

[image: error message]

Comment: Post the stack trace as text, not as an image. And post the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using incompatible versions of spring-test and spring-boot. spring-test calls `SpringApplicationContextLoader.getResourceSuffixes` (plural form) [since v4.1.0.RC2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/35c372f200258f74721a82441a03313ee21fb315#diff-7d5f86be5b40ab7a355acab9db0191a5L195). spring-boot's `SpringApplicationContextLoader.getResourceSufffix` (singular) throws that exception [since v1.3.0.RC1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d01bc41e1e9acb0b76795ad6f7f4c4e160a096e2).

You would have to either upgrade to spring-test >= 4.1.0 or downgrade to spring-boot < 1.3.0

Comment: Oh, sorry - spring moved the test classes back into the framework repository. You need to upgrade your spring-test dependency to > 4.1.0

Comment: Okay, I changed that tot 4.2.5. I think that error is resolved. Now, I get a few other errors I don't understand: http://puu.sh/nM1FB/b39002b018.png

Comment: @John if this answer resolved the problem described in your question, it would be nice to upvote + accept this answer, and ask a completely new question with the next problems you're experiencing